# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy iniciando con android studio asi que no conozco mucho sobre el programa y tengo este error Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
he intentado investigar pero todas las soluciones no me funcionan o no van con mi problema, como ya dije, soy nuevo en esto asi que no tengo la menor idea de como arreglarlo.

**este es mi Manifest y mi gradle**

````
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.drastosito.aaaaaaaaaaa">




    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ptlogo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ptlogo_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AAAAAAAAAAA">
        <activity
            android:name=".PrimeraInferfaz"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_primera_inferfaz"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AAAAAAAAAAA.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



    </application>```
````

Comment: ¿Qué te dice el log?

Comment: Usualmente las librerías tienen su propio manifest que android trata de unir con el del propio proyecto, en Android Studio abre tu manifest y hay una pestaña abajo a la  izquierda que puedes ver el Merged Manifest y allí te saldrán en caso de errores cuáles son